# When looking at a message (in its own window) in Apple Mail, how can I jump to the thread that contains it?

Tags: osx-mavericks, apple-mail

For example, if I pull up a message from Spotlight, it's not threaded or grouped with related messages -- it's in its own window.  I would like to be able to see or jump to the related messages view.